# Angularjs : view not refreshing after second and more visit of the page

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript, angular-ui-router, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am new for angularjs and coffeescript.I have one problem in refreshing views.

This is the scenario :

I have two types of pages :

1. List of mixed vehicle listed. On this page I have option "add to fourwheeler" and "add to twowheeler".
2. Second page contains two tabs 1. Twowheeler 2. Fourwheeler

Now after login into app first I visit to page 1 and choose one vehicle for add to fourwheeler then go to page 2 and select fourwheeler tab I found recently added vehicle but now if I again go to page 1 -> choose vehicle for fourwheeler and check in page 2 fourwheeler tab then I don't found that item.

When I check in console, I found new item in data return by API but missing in view. So I conclude that view is not refreshing. So How can I refresh view every time when I visit this page ?

**I think I have to put $scope.$apply(). But I don't know where should I use this one ?**

Code:

State file :

```
angular.module('states.vehicles', [])
  .config ($stateProvider) ->
    $stateProvider
      .state "app.vehicles",
        url:         "/vehicles/:itemType"
        views: {
          app: {
            controller:  'VehiclesCtrl'
            templateUrl: "templates/vehicles/vehicles.jade"
          }
        }
        abstract:            true
        data:
          isRoot:            true
          showBannerAd:      true
          tabs:
            twowheeler:
              name: 'Twowheeler'
              direction: 'app.vehicles.items({itemType: "twowheeler"})'
              id: 'twowheeler'
              icon: 'icon-twowheeler'
            fourwheeler:
              name: 'Fourwheeler'
              direction: 'app.vehicles.items({itemType: "fourwheeler"})'
              id: 'fourwheeler'
              icon: 'icon-fourwheeler'

      .state 'app.vehicles.items',
        url:         ''
        views: {
          tabs: {
            templateUrl: 'templates/vehicles/vehicles.items.jade'
            controller:  'vehiclesItemsCtrl'
          }
        }
        resolve:
          items: ($stateParams, Vehicle) ->
            offset = $stateParams.queryOffset || 0
            Vehicle.query
              type:   $stateParams.itemType
              count:  10
              offset: offset
        data:
          isTab: true
          loadingTransition: true
```

Controller  file:

```
class VehiclesItemsCtrl extends BaseCtrl
  @register 'VehiclesItemsCtrl'

  @inject '$scope', '$state', '$stateParams', 'Vehicle'

  initialize: ->
    @$scope.itemType = @$stateParams.itemType
    @$scope.items    = []
    @$scope.query    = @_vehicleQuery

  # Private

  _vehicleQuery: =>
    @$stateParams.queryOffset = @$scope.items.length
    @$state.current.resolve.items(@$stateParams, @Vehicle)
```

View file :

```
ion-view(title='Vehicles')
  ion-content.v-offset-nav
    section(ng-switch='itemType')
      div(ng-switch-when='twowheeler')
        section(ng-repeat="twowheeler in items", ui-sref='app.twowheeler({twowheelerId: twowheeler.twowheeler_id})')
          a.row.list-item.list-colors
            h3 {{twowheeler.name}}
      div(ng-switch-when='fourwheeler')
        section(ng-repeat="fourwheeler in items", ui-sref='app.fourwheeler({fourwheelerId: fourwheeler.fourwheeler_id})')
          a.row.list-item.list-colors
            h3 {{fourwheeler.name}}
      nfinite-scroll(items='items', query='query')
```

Please let me know what I have to change?

Comment: use angular 2 and forget $scope.$apply()

Answer (score 0):

```
ion-view(cache-view="false", title='Vehicles')
```

I added **cache-view="false"** in ion-view tag and it works perfect as I want.